Why did the New Testament writers, when quoting the Old Testament, refrain from using the Tetragrammaton (YHWH)?
The New Testament writers often quote the Old Testament. When quoting the Old Testament passages that contain the Name (i.e., the Tetragrammaton), they use the substitution Greek word typically found in the Septuagint.
Why?
Examples:
Luke 20:42-44 NASB  quoted from Psalm 110:1

42 For David himself says in the book of Psalms, ‘The Lord said to my Lord, “Sit at My right hand, 43 Until I make Your enemies a footstool for Your feet.”’ 44 Therefore David calls Him ‘Lord,’ and how is He his son?”

Matthew 4:7 NASB quoted from Deuteronomy 6:16

Jesus answered him, “It is also written: ‘Do not put the Lord your God to the test.’”

Romans 10:13 NASB quoted from Joel 2:32

... for, 'Everyone who calls on the name of the Lord will be saved.'

Hebrews 10:30 NASB quoted from Deuteronomy 32:35

For we know him who said, 'It is mine to avenge; I will repay,'

1 Peter 3:12 NASB quoted from Psalm 34:16

For the eyes of the Lord are on the righteous and his ears are attentive to their prayer, but the face of the Lord is against those who do evil.

In all of these quoted passages from the Old Testament, the Name (i.e., Tetragrammaton) is replaced by the New Testament writers by the Greek word "kyrios" (i.e., "Lord"). There are theories and traditions as to why the Name went into disuse via substitution (in both/either letter and speech).
The only possible correlation that I can think of is that this substitution word (i.e., "kyrios") is also used as a title and designation used for Christ Jesus throughout the New Testament. Thus, this could be a method by which the New Testament authors are equating [the name of] Jesus to the Name (as indicated by Philippians 2:5-11).
Is this why the New Testament writers, when quoting the Old Testament, refrained from using the Tetragrammaton? Is there a better explanation?

Two reasons. First, Jewish tradition forbid the use of God's name outside of Hebrew. Not taking the LORD's name in vain is one of the 10 commandments - and so they treat his revealed name with great respect; and they avoid sinning by not using his name outside of Hebrew. I think they may also restrict usage of God's name to the synagogue / liturgical use. Second, pretty much every single quotation of the Hebrew Bible within the NT comes from the Septuagint. The Septuagint was well known and used by the Jewish community in the 1st century CE.

That makes sense. I've read some theories that the Name was originally substituted when the Septuagint -- a Greek translation of Hebrew scriptures -- was created. I suppose that the 70 might have wanted to avoid any semblance of enabling the abuse, misuse or any/all vain use of God's Name.And, of course, the letters of the Tetragrammaton are HEBREW. I suppose that this might have created a non-equivalent "name" into Greek.

I will note, however, that in at least one location (Exodus 3) they did translate the name as “ego eimi ho on” = the one who is = the being.

@RyanPierceWilliams ... As Dottard indicates some early manuscripts of the LXX do use the Tetragrammaton... The NT seems to have been written during a transitional period.

The reasons for the NT practice of uniformly substituting kyrios for the Hebrew YHWH (when quoting the OT) are several:

the NT was written in Greek and not Hebrew; YHWH is a Hebrew word that has no equivalent in Greek.  The closest Non-Hebrew languages can come is use the phrase "I am" as was used by Jesus in 14 places in the NT such as John 6:20, 8:24, 28, 58, 13:9, etc.
The vowels for the pronunciation of the sacred name, YHWH, had been lost by NT times.  But even before this, when reading OT Hebrew, a well-schooled Hebrew would never pronounce the sacred name, but substitute the word "Adonai" which simply means "Lord", ie, "kyrios' in Greek.  The inspired NT writers obviously continued the practice.
Only a very few of the Septuagint MSS attempt to reproduce any form of the Tetragrammaton: The oldest LXX MSS (P. Ryl. 458) has blank spaces, or others have ΙΑΩ (= “IAO”) in an attempt to transliterate the holy name.  Some very early Greek LXX MSS even have the Tetragrammaton in paleo-Hebrew letters.
However, all the LXX MSS prepared by Christians from earliest times uniformly replaced the Tetragrammaton with kyrios (= “Lord”).

Thus, as this answer shows >> Translation of Matt 22:44, "The Lord said to my Lord ... "  the inspired writers almost uniformly used "kyrios" to translate the Tetragrammaton, as the OP has already pointed out.

They came up with a Translation for it in the Septuagint: “ego eimi ho on” = the being = the one who is.

@RyanPierceWilliams - to which verse are you alluding/quoting?

in Exodus 3 where the angel gives the name of God
